# AppInventor2 TCP client extension crashes the app

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, app-inventor

I have been using a tcp client extension by Jean-Rodolphe Letertre for app inventor 2 and it works flawlessly until you call the disconnect method and than it crashes the app. After looking at the code for the extension i found that disconnect only shuts down output, input and than closes the socket which shouldn't cause any crashes so my suspicion fell on the connect method which runs a thread because it keeps reading data in a loop from a tcp socket and when we call disconnect we don't finish the thread which causes application crash because input is closed and an exception goes unhandled.

**NOTE:** The code is not mine and i don't ask to fix it for me i only want to know if iv'e found the problem which causes crashes and if so i will fix it myself. Thanks in advance for any help!

The code:

```
// -*- mode: java; c-basic-offset: 2; -*-
// Copyright 2009-2011 Google, All Rights reserved
// Copyright 2011-2012 MIT, All rights reserved
// Released under the Apache License, Version 2.0
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

package com.gmail.at.moicjarod;

import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.*;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.util.RuntimeErrorAlert;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.DesignerComponent;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.DesignerProperty;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.PropertyCategory;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.SimpleEvent;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.SimpleFunction;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.SimpleObject;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.SimpleProperty;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.UsesLibraries;
import com.google.appinventor.components.annotations.UsesPermissions;
import com.google.appinventor.components.common.ComponentCategory;
import com.google.appinventor.components.common.PropertyTypeConstants;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.util.AsynchUtil;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.util.ErrorMessages;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.util.YailList;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.util.SdkLevel;

import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.errors.YailRuntimeError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.StrictMode;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

/**
 * Simple Client Socket
 * @author moicjarod@gmail.com (Jean-Rodolphe Letertre)
 * with the help of the work of lizlooney @ google.com (Liz Looney) and josmasflores @ gmail.com (Jose Dominguez)
 * the help of Alexey Brylevskiy for debugging
 * and the help of Hossein Amerkashi from AppyBuilder for compatibility with AppyBuilder
 */
@DesignerComponent(version = 4,
  description = "Non-visible component that provides client socket connectivity.",
  category = ComponentCategory.EXTENSION,
  nonVisible = true,
  iconName = "http://jr.letertre.free.fr/Projets/AIClientSocket/clientsocket.png")
  @SimpleObject(external = true)
  @UsesPermissions(permissionNames = "android.permission.INTERNET")


public class ClientSocketAI2Ext extends AndroidNonvisibleComponent implements Component
{
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "ClientSocketAI2Ext";

  private final Activity activity;

  // the socket object
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  // the address to connect to
  private String serverAddress = "";
  // the port to connect to
  private String serverPort = "";
  // boolean that indicates the state of the connection, true = connected, false = not connected
  private boolean connectionState = false;
  // boolean that indicates the mode used, false = string sent as is, true = String is considered as hexadecimal data and will be converted before sending
  // same behavior is used when receiving data
  private boolean hexaStringMode = false;

  InputStream inputStream = null;

  /**
   * Creates a new Client Socket component.
   *
   * @param container the Form that this component is contained in.
   */
  public ClientSocketAI2Ext(ComponentContainer container)
  {
    super(container.$form());
    activity = container.$context();
    // compatibility with AppyBuilder (thx Hossein Amerkashi <kkashi01 [at] gmail [dot] com>)
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }

  /**
   * Method that returns the server's address.
   */
  @SimpleProperty(category = PropertyCategory.BEHAVIOR, description = "The address of the server the client will connect to.")
  public String ServerAddress()
  {
    return serverAddress;
  }

  /**
   * Method to specify the server's address
   */
  @DesignerProperty(editorType = PropertyTypeConstants.PROPERTY_TYPE_STRING)
  @SimpleProperty
  public void ServerAddress(String address)
  {
    serverAddress = address;
  }

  /**
   * Method that returns the server's port.
   */
  @SimpleProperty(category = PropertyCategory.BEHAVIOR, description = "The port of the server the client will connect to.")
  public String ServerPort()
  {
    return serverPort;
  }

  /**
   * Method to specify the server's port
   */
  @DesignerProperty(editorType = PropertyTypeConstants.PROPERTY_TYPE_STRING)
  @SimpleProperty
  public void ServerPort(String port)
  {
    serverPort = port;
  }

  /**
   * Method that returns the connection state
   */
  @SimpleProperty(category = PropertyCategory.BEHAVIOR, description = "The state of the connection - true = connected, false = disconnected")
  public boolean ConnectionState()
  {
    return connectionState;
  }

  /**
   * Method that returns the mode (string or hexastring)
   */
  @SimpleProperty(category = PropertyCategory.BEHAVIOR, description = "The mode of sending and receiving data.")
  public boolean HexaStringMode()
  {
    return hexaStringMode;
  }

  /**
   * Method to specify the mode (string or hexastring)
   */
  @DesignerProperty(editorType = PropertyTypeConstants.PROPERTY_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
  @SimpleProperty
  public void HexaStringMode(boolean mode)
  {
    hexaStringMode = mode;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the socket, connect to the server and launches the thread to receive data from server
   */
  @SimpleFunction(description = "Tries to connect to the server and launches the thread for receiving data (blocking until connected or failed)")
  public void Connect()
  {
    if (connectionState == true)
    {
      throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error, socket connected yet, please disconnect before reconnect !", "Error");
    }
    try
    {
      // connecting the socket
      clientSocket = new Socket();
      clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, Integer.parseInt(serverPort)), 5000);
      connectionState = true;
      // begin the receive loop in a new thread
      AsynchUtil.runAsynchronously(new Runnable()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int bytesRead;

          try
          {
            // get the input stream and save the data
            inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            while (true)
            {
              // test if there is a server problem then close socket properly (thx Axeley :-))
              try
              {
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
                if(bytesRead == -1)
                  break;
              }
              catch(SocketException e)
              {
                if(e.getMessage().indexOf("ETIMEDOUT") >= 0)
                  break;
                throw e;
              }
              byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
              final String dataReceived;
              // hexaStringMode is false, so we don't transform the string received
              if (hexaStringMode == false)
              {
                dataReceived = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
              }
              // hexaStringMode is true, so we make a string with each character as an hexa symbol representing the received message
              else
              {
                int i;
                char hexaSymbol1, hexaSymbol2;
                String tempData = "";
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                for (i = 0; i < byteArrayOutputStream.size(); i++)
                {
                  if (((byteArray[i] & 0xF0) >> 4) < 0xA)
                  // 0 to 9 symbol
                  hexaSymbol1 = (char)(((byteArray[i] & 0xF0) >> 4) + 0x30);
                  else
                    // A to F symbol
                    hexaSymbol1 = (char)(((byteArray[i] & 0xF0) >> 4) + 0x37);
                  if ((byteArray[i] & 0x0F) < 0xA)
                  hexaSymbol2 = (char)((byteArray[i] & 0x0F) + 0x30);
                  else
                    hexaSymbol2 = (char)((byteArray[i] & 0x0F) + 0x37);
                  tempData = tempData + hexaSymbol1 + hexaSymbol2;
                }

                dataReceived = tempData;
              }
              // reset of the byteArrayOutputStream to flush the content
              byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
              // then we send the data to the user using an event
              // events must be sent by the main thread (UI)
              activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
              {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                  DataReceived(dataReceived);
                }
              } );
            }
            // When we go there, either we have
            // - server shutdown
            // - disconnection asked (inputstream closed => -1 returned)
            // - connection problem
            // so, if it is not disconnected yet, we disconnect the socket and inform the user of it.
            if (connectionState == true)
            {
              Disconnect();
              // events must be sent by the main thread (UI)
              activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
              {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                  RemoteConnectionClosed();
                }
              } );
            }
          }
          catch (SocketException e)
          {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_READ", e);
            throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error (read)" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_READ", e);
            throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error (read)", "Error");
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            connectionState = false;
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_READ", e);
            throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error (read)" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
          }
        }
      } );
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_CONNECT", e);
      throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      connectionState = false;
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_CONNECT", e);
      throw new YailRuntimeError("Connect error (Socket Creation)" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Send data through the socket to the server
   */
  @SimpleFunction(description = "Send data to the server")
  public void SendData(final String data)
  {
    final byte [] dataToSend;
    byte [] dataCopy = data.getBytes();
    if (connectionState == false)
    {
      throw new YailRuntimeError("Send error, socket not connected.", "Error");
    }

    if (hexaStringMode == false)
    {
      //dataSend = new byte [data.length()];
      // if hexaStringMode is false, we send data as is
      dataToSend = data.getBytes();
    }
    else
    {
      // if hexaStringMode is true, we begin to verify we can transcode the symbols
      // verify if the data we want to send contains only hexa symbols
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
      {
        if (((dataCopy[i] < 0x30) || (dataCopy[i] > 0x39)) && ((dataCopy[i] < 0x41) || (dataCopy[i] > 0x46)) && ((dataCopy[i] < 0x61) || (dataCopy[i] > 0x66)))
          throw new YailRuntimeError("Send data : hexaStringMode is selected and non hexa symbol found in send String.", "Error");
      }
      // verify that the number of symbols is even
      if ((data.length() %2) == 1)
      {
        throw new YailRuntimeError("Send data : hexaStringMode is selected and send String length is odd. Even number of characters needed.", "Error");
      }
      // if all tests pass, we transcode the data :
      dataToSend=new byte[data.length()/2+1];
      for (i = 0; i < data.length(); i=i+2)
      {
        byte [] temp1 = new byte [2];
        temp1 [0] = dataCopy[i];
        temp1 [1] = dataCopy[i+1];
        String temp2 = new String (temp1);
        dataToSend[i/2]=(byte)Integer.parseInt(temp2, 16);
      }
      // end of c-type string character
      dataToSend[i/2] = (byte)0x00;
    }

    // we then send asynchonously the data
    AsynchUtil.runAsynchronously(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          OutputStream out;
          out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
          out.write(dataToSend);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_SEND", e);
          throw new YailRuntimeError("Send data" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_UNABLE_TO_SEND_DATA", e);
          throw new YailRuntimeError("Send Data", "Error");
        }
      }
    } );
  }

  /**
   * Close the socket
   */
  @SimpleFunction(description = "Disconnect to the server")
  public void Disconnect()
  {
    if (connectionState == true)
    {
      connectionState = false;
      try
      {
        // shutdown the input socket,
        clientSocket.shutdownInput();
        clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
        clientSocket.close();
      }
      catch (SocketException e)
      {
        // modifications by axeley too :-)
        if(e.getMessage().indexOf("ENOTCONN") == -1)
        {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_CONNECT", e);
          throw new YailRuntimeError("Disconnect" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
         }
         // if not connected, then just ignore the exception
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_CONNECT", e);
        throw new YailRuntimeError("Disconnect" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR_CONNECT", e);
        throw new YailRuntimeError("Disconnect" + e.getMessage(), "Error");
      }
      finally
      {
        clientSocket=null;
      }

    }
    else
      throw new YailRuntimeError("Socket not connected, can't disconnect.", "Error");
  }

  /**
   * Event indicating that a message has been received
   *
   * @param data the data sent by the server
   */
  @SimpleEvent
  public void DataReceived(String data)
  {
    // invoke the application's "DataReceived" event handler.
    EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(this, "DataReceived", data);
  }

  /**
   * Event indicating that the remote socket closed the connection
   *
   */
  @SimpleEvent
  public void RemoteConnectionClosed()
  {
    // invoke the application's "RemoteConnectionClosed" event handler.
    EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(this, "RemoteConnectionClosed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By commenting the following lines, it could be achieved:

```
throw new YailRuntimeError("...
```

The problem on this approach is that we wouldn't be able do know the disconnection reason, however we must agree that these messages are rather informative than functional in the sense of the application workflow, therefore an alternative option is to add the ability to disable these calls in runtime.

Comment: BTW, Jean-Rodolphe Letertre has updated a new release on MIT Application forum Google group, on which it is possible to deactivate these messages.